# Accessing JSON column after reading multiple objects

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

**The Problem**

I'm having an issue trying to solve a particular problem, I wish to read in a file that contains multiple json objects and access each object's values at the same time. So far I have it reading the json object in like this:

```
with open(infile) as file:
    allcontent = []
    for line in file:
        allcontent.append(json.loads(line))
```

The contents of the list are simply a json object per item:

`[{"price": 241, "owner": "brian"}]`

`[{"price": 243, "owner": "bob"}]`

This works and simply appends each json object to the list. However as I wish to calculate for example the highest price across each item in the list I cannot fathom a simple way to perform the operation without a complex loop and assigning variables to track each columns value.

I tried looping over the each json object and accessing the key and value, but I dont want to use this method as it seems like there should be a simpler way to access a column from a list of json objects, specifically for just 1 column of information on each item:

```
for line in file:
    for key,value in line.items():
        print(key,value)
```

**Question**

---

Using this method does print out each of the rows keys and values, however I need to access all of the rows prices at once to find the highest and lowest. Is there a simpler way than with a loop? such as `allcontent['prices']`

**Dictionaries**

I attempted to use a dictionary however as updating the dictionary overrides the previously updated content as the keys are identical `"prices"` for example and would require a number of conditions to test if the new value is higher or lower than the previously updated one.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `min((thing['price'] for thing in allcontent))`?

Comment: yeh exactly like that, something to reduce my use of loops and let me target all columns in my list but also within the json object itself if it makes sense, since my list contains a json object im not sure i can use thing['price'] to access it since it contains a json object...but yes this is exactly what im looking for theoretically

Comment: I suggested yesterday (on a non-dupe question) using `json.load()` instead of `loads()` because your file appeared to be valid json that could be read in one piece. Did this not work? Even if it didn't, you need only loop through this once and never bother making `allcontent` if this is the only purpose; keep track of the running max and min with two extra variables while iterating through `file`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a sample of the input file.

Comment: .load did work however as the input file im provided contains a list of objects there were errors when using .load as it is essentially just a string im reading from the file so it works but i would have to restructure my file to solve it which i cant do

Comment: If there were numerous errors then `load` did not work. How large is this list and is time absolutely critical? Do you actually need `allcontent` for some task later, or are you just looking for max/min? Note that the proposed solutions still have to iterate through and build a list, and then iterate through that whole list. If we know the size of the file we can work out if there's meaningful gains.

Comment: time is critical as the file is very large, i was keeping all content merely for debugging currently until i get a final specification incase other operations than min and max are needed

Comment: In that case I will see if I can get something faster than the current ones with a large file, assuming that you'll eventually scrap `allcontent` after debugging. Will be interesting to see if/where a tipping point exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some benchmarks. The fastest I could get it was in `Method 1` with 1mil lines (I've hashed the code out to generate the data but it takes maybe 30 secs to unhash and make your own). `Method 2` and `Method 3` are my representations of the answer by BorrajaX (the former of which actually allows you to keep all of the read-in data for further use). `Method 4` is your original, with some hope of keeping the value of your `print`. I removed all `print` statements.

This is in Python 2.7. But really the gains here are actually pretty small even with 1,000,000 lines of text.

```
import time
import json
import string
import numpy as np

############################# GENERATE RANDOM DATA #############################

#letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
#random_data = ["""{"price": %d, "owner": "%s"}""" % (np.random.randint(1, 1000), 
#                ''.join(np.random.choice(letters, 6, replace=False))) for x 
#                in xrange(1000000)]
#
#with open('pseudo_json.txt', 'w') as outfile:
#    for line in random_data:
#        outfile.write(str(line) +'\n')


time1 = time.time()
#################################### METHOD 1 ##################################

running_max = 0
with open('pseudo_json.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        price = json.loads(line)['price']
        if price > running_max:
            running_max = price

time2 = time.time()

#################################### METHOD 2 ##################################

with open("pseudo_json.txt", 'r') as f:
    allcontent = []
    for line in f:
        allcontent.append(json.loads(line))

the_max = (max(allcontent, key=lambda x: x['price']))

time3 = time.time()

##################################### METHOD 3 ##############################

the_max = 0
with open("pseudo_json.txt", 'r') as f:
    the_max = (max(f, key=lambda x: json.loads(x)['price']))

time4 = time.time()

#################################### ORIGINAL ##################################

with open("pseudo_json.txt", 'r') as infile:
    allcontent = []
    for line in infile:
        allcontent.append(json.loads(line))

values = []

for line in allcontent:
    for key,value in line.items():
        values.append(value)

the_max = max(values)

time5 = time.time()

################################# READING FILE #################################

with open("pseudo_json.txt", 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        pass

time6 = time.time()

################################### RESULTS ####################################

print "Without storage and max took: {}".format(time2 - time1)
print "With storage and using max took: {}".format(time3-time2)
print "Without storage but using max took: {}".format(time4 - time3)
print "Original took: {}".format(time5 - time4)
print "Reading file took: {}".format(time6 - time5)
```

Comment: sweet mother of god....this site needs to allow people to upvote more than once....im gonna try all of these now out of interest....

Comment: :) There may be faster ways yet, but I'm missing one crucial test that I'll do now. I think the real issue is `I/O`, so we should look at reading the file.

Comment: @Dean219 added the extra test. Iterating through the file was less heavy than I thought. I actually quite enjoyed this; using `max` on a complete list was actually faster than I first assumed so I have some learning to do too :)

Comment: im still testing them at the moment all of them do exactly what i was asking for earlier so thats extremely helpful so if i can find the best performance that would just be a bonus. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

For what I gathered from the question (and I might be wrong) your problems seems to reduce to finding the JSON object (which actually gets loaded into a Python dictionary) with the maximum price (for instance), right?

You could just load all the file in memory (put all its items into the `allcontent` list of dictionaries) the way you're already doing it, then use the built in [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) function.

```
import json

with open("data.json", 'r') as f:
    allcontent = []
    for line in f:
        allcontent.append(json.loads(line))

print(max(allcontent, key=lambda x: x['price']))
```

... which outputs the whole JSON object (a.k.a *dictionary*):

```
{u'owner': u'bob', u'price': 243}
```

However, since the file itself it's an iterable, you don't even need to preload it in `allcontent`. You could just do:

```
with open("data.json", 'r') as f:
    print(max(f, key=lambda x: json.loads(x)['price']))
```

All this assumes that your file looks exactly like this:

```
{"price":241,"owner":"brian"}
{"price":243,"owner":"bob"}
```

... which is not valid JSON

**PS 01:** I would strongly suggest you don't name your `infile`'s file descriptor *"file"*, since that would shadow the built-in [`file`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file) function.

**PS 02:** 
As per your comment in the question:

> .load did work however as the input file im provided contains a list of objects there were errors when using .load as it is essentially just a string im reading from the file

If you wanted to use [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load), your file needs to be valid JSON. For what you have provided in the example, the closest valid JSON I can think of would be:

```
[
 {"price":241,"owner":"brian"},
 {"price":243,"owner":"bob"}
]
```

Notice that it creates a list (starting with `[` and ending with `]`) and that every item in the list is separated by a comma (except the last). I personally check Json's validity using the page [JSONLint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) (but I'm sure there are many others)

Comment: For PS 02, the example on the other question yesterday was `[{"values":"test","cost":"1234"},{"values":"test2","cost":"12345"}]` so that's why I assumed OP could `load` since that was actually valid json. Now I'm guessing it's `\n` separated.

Comment: what @roganjosh stated is correct, after recieving a new file it had been modified and results in some changes, your methods using the lambda seems to work for this question though

Comment: @roganjosh, I see... Yeah, I imagine there's something invalid in that Json file (that's why I added the note of how the file would need to be in order for the sample code to work)

Comment: @BorrajaX I did some benchmarks in answer below. I hope I reproduced your examples reasonably. I'm actually quite surprised on the results; your very first code block actually comes pretty close to a solution runtime that discards all of the data; unless there were memory issues, I'd take your first approach I think.

Comment: Thanks for the tests @roganjosh! (can't _upvote_ yet, since I reached my daily quota) but I will. Thanks again **:-)**

Comment: @BorrajaX No worries, it actually made me quite curious because I thought for sure that a simple `if` in the first iteration of the file would have been a _lot_ faster than `(max(allcontent, key=lambda x: x['price']))`. I was faster, but I had to lose 1mil lines of data for what turned out to be very marginal gains :)

Answer (score 1):

The result of `json.loads` is usually* a regular Python dictionary. That means that, in your example, the `allcontent` variable is just a list of dictionaries.

You can therefore use Python's [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#min) and [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#max) functions, combined with a comprehension:

```
>>> allcontent = [{'price': 1}, {'price': 2}]
>>> min((thing['price'] for thing in allcontent))
1
```

---

*: Of course, if you do `json.loads("0")` you just get an integer.